# Internal server error in a tomcat servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am writing a java servlet for a REST interface using jersey. I have the following really weird problem: As soon as I POST to some resource I receive an internal server error (status 500). the localhost_access_log*.txt shows entries of the form

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Jan/2015:18:04:30 +0100] "POST /server/rest/requests HTTP/1.1" 500 1039
```

indicating the problem. However, I see no concrete error message, i.e. some kind of exception being thrown on the console (I am currently using eclipse). After the indication

```
INFO: Server startup in 5476 ms
```

Nothing appears any more. The start goes smooth without any problems as well. Also, it seems like the error occurs before any of my handler code is executed, as a corresponding breakpoint in eclipse is never reached. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get a handle on what is actually happening?

Comment: Check in your browser network console what is returned for the error 500

Comment: Are you making the HTTP POST request with empty payload/body?

Comment: Well, empty parameters generally trigger a` NullPointerException` in the worst case... And that exception actually *does* show up...

Comment: So you have no stack trace of this exception? can you add the API method code for the POST?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got it. I was using `genson` to convert between JSON / Java classes. Unfortunately the package silently fails when it receives malformed input and the server reacts by returning the internal error message...

Comment: This sounds strange...Genson does throw an exception for malformed json. Isn't it jersey that swallows the error? Could you please provide an example of incoming request that fails silently?